# Fixed effects estimation with felm from lfe package causes rank-deficiency

Tags: r, linear-regression, panel-data

I'm trying to estimate a dif-in-dif-regression with time fixed and firm fixed effects. My model consists of a dummy for the treatment group (`treat`), a dummy for the days during which the treatment was active (`ban`), the dif-in-dif estimator (`treat.ban`) which is the product of the other two dummies (`treat * ban`) and some control variables.

When I estimate the model without fixed effects it works fine. Including fixed effects leads to the following warning:

> Warning message: In chol.default(mat, pivot = TRUE, tol = tol) :   the
>   matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite

See the regression summary with some sample data (note that with the original sample results are more plausible, but I still face the problem of `NAs` in the coefficients of the `treat` and the `ban` dummies):

```
library(lfe)
library(dplyr)

reg1 <- felm(dynmes ~ treat + ban + treat.ban + log(total.assets) 
             + market.to.book + leverage | symbol + date,
             data = temp)

> summary(reg1)

Call:
   felm(formula = dynmes ~ treat + ban + treat.ban + log(total.assets) + 
                  market.to.book + leverage | symbol + date, data = temp) 

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.052129 -0.024407 -0.002392  0.019482  0.075099 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
treatTRUE               NA         NA      NA       NA  
banTRUE                 NA         NA      NA       NA  
treat.banTRUE     0.037566   0.020848   1.802   0.0761 .
log(total.assets)       NA         NA      NA       NA  
market.to.book    0.199361   0.081149   2.457   0.0167 *
leverage          0.004716   0.009160   0.515   0.6084  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.03534 on 66 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared(full model): 0.892   Adjusted R-squared: 0.838 
Multiple R-squared(proj model): 0.1625   Adjusted R-squared: -0.2563 
F-statistic(full model):16.52 on 33 and 66 DF, p-value: < 2.2e-16 
F-statistic(proj model): 2.134 on 6 and 66 DF, p-value: 0.06093 


Warning message:
In chol.default(mat, pivot = TRUE, tol = tol) :
  the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite
```

My concern is that the dif-in-dif coefficient `treat.ban` may be biased as it may catch some of the effects that should actually be covered by the `ban` and the `treat` dummies.
I guess that collinearity of the dummy variables causes this problem but I haven't found a way how to handle it. I've read the lfe vignettes and I've also tried to change the order in the second part of the formula (that is: `... | date + symbol`) without succeeding. Further I've found some general advices on how to handle collinearity (e.g. [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it) post on stackexchange), but no solution for my case.

I'm not sure if this question rather should be placed on stackexchange in case that it is a general statistical problem if one tries to include e.g. time fixed effects in a regression with a time dummy. But I guess it's more a computational or rather coding issue, which is why I post it here.

Here is a subsample of my orginal data set which I used for the regression example above (my original sample is about 200,000 rows which is why I use `felm` in the first place):

```
temp <- structure(list(symbol = c("AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", 
"AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", 
"AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", 
"AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", 
"AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", "AT_ABCB", 
"AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", 
"AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", 
"AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", 
"AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", 
"AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACFC", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", 
"AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", 
"AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", 
"AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", 
"AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", 
"AT_ACGL", "AT_ACGL", "AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI", 
"AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI", 
"AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI", "AT_AFSI"
), date = structure(c(14132, 14133, 14134, 14137, 14138, 14139, 
14140, 14141, 14144, 14145, 14146, 14147, 14148, 14151, 14152, 
14153, 14154, 14155, 14158, 14159, 14160, 14161, 14162, 14165, 
14166, 14167, 14168, 14169, 14132, 14133, 14134, 14137, 14138, 
14139, 14140, 14141, 14144, 14145, 14146, 14147, 14148, 14151, 
14152, 14153, 14154, 14155, 14158, 14159, 14160, 14161, 14162, 
14165, 14166, 14167, 14168, 14169, 14132, 14133, 14134, 14137, 
14138, 14139, 14140, 14141, 14144, 14145, 14146, 14147, 14148, 
14151, 14152, 14153, 14154, 14155, 14158, 14159, 14160, 14161, 
14162, 14165, 14166, 14167, 14168, 14169, 14132, 14133, 14134, 
14137, 14138, 14139, 14140, 14141, 14144, 14145, 14146, 14147, 
14148, 14151, 14152, 14153), class = "Date"), dynmes = c(0.1, 
0.11, 0.098, 0.087, 0.101, 0.128, 0.185, 0.262, 0.257, 0.226, 
0.201, 0.186, 0.178, 0.17, 0.208, 0.271, 0.271, 0.24, 0.233, 
0.202, 0.27, 0.26, 0.277, 0.362, 0.346, 0.315, 0.321, 0.354, 
0.031, 0.024, 0.038, 0.03, 0.028, 0.026, 0.077, 0.11, 0.146, 
0.128, 0.098, 0.123, 0.104, 0.086, 0.069, 0.114, 0.105, 0.166, 
0.165, 0.125, 0.108, 0.095, 0.104, 0.081, 0.143, 0.232, 0.225, 
0.219, 0.033, 0.032, 0.03, 0.028, 0.025, 0.034, 0.031, 0.04, 
0.046, 0.059, 0.055, 0.05, 0.046, 0.042, 0.042, 0.042, 0.039, 
0.037, 0.035, 0.038, 0.044, 0.048, 0.063, 0.062, 0.082, 0.081, 
0.081, 0.079, 0.049, 0.06, 0.06, 0.061, 0.061, 0.055, 0.058, 
0.053, 0.075, 0.068, 0.078, 0.093, 0.105, 0.09, 0.11, 0.119), 
    total.assets = c(2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 
    2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 
    2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 
    2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 2106528, 
    2106528, 2106528, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 
    931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 
    931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 
    931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 931026, 15567216, 
    15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 
    15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 
    15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 
    15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 
    15567216, 15567216, 15567216, 2286292, 2286292, 2286292, 
    2286292, 2286292, 2286292, 2286292, 2286292, 2286292, 2286292, 
    2286292, 2286292, 2286292, 2286292, 2286292, 2286292), treat = c(TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE), ban = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE
    ), treat.ban = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE), market.to.book = c(0.913, 0.915, 0.91, 0.864, 0.938, 
    0.802, 0.995, 1.067, 1.047, 1.025, 0.993, 1.031, 0.99, 0.867, 
    1.051, 0.963, 0.983, 0.923, 0.913, 0.743, 0.79, 0.701, 0.919, 
    1.002, 0.954, 0.847, 1.006, 0.958, 1.192, 1.149, 1.15, 1.14, 
    1.131, 1.032, 0.939, 1.044, 1.013, 1.013, 1.103, 1.083, 1.071, 
    1.065, 1.179, 1.143, 0.992, 1.059, 1.059, 1.038, 1.06, 1.007, 
    1.004, 0.855, 1.077, 1.188, 1.082, 1.083, 1.15, 1.139, 1.142, 
    1.147, 1.214, 1.209, 1.279, 1.342, 1.234, 1.221, 1.228, 1.234, 
    1.224, 1.193, 1.218, 1.222, 1.205, 1.216, 1.179, 1.125, 1.078, 
    0.988, 0.958, 1.078, 1.04, 0.995, 0.959, 0.981, 1.93, 1.885, 
    1.841, 1.798, 1.805, 1.758, 1.74, 1.873, 1.853, 1.957, 1.819, 
    1.951, 1.963, 1.798, 1.927, 1.764), leverage = c(11.965, 
    11.94, 11.999, 12.594, 11.676, 13.485, 11.068, 10.386, 10.564, 
    10.769, 11.082, 10.715, 11.111, 12.547, 10.525, 11.401, 11.191, 
    11.847, 11.965, 14.484, 13.675, 15.288, 11.898, 10.997, 11.501, 
    12.817, 10.954, 11.455, 8.861, 9.153, 9.144, 9.219, 9.285, 
    10.081, 10.98, 9.975, 10.245, 10.245, 9.491, 9.646, 9.745, 
    9.795, 8.943, 9.197, 10.443, 9.845, 9.845, 10.027, 9.833, 
    10.3, 10.329, 11.958, 9.695, 8.882, 9.659, 9.646, 3.484, 
    3.508, 3.503, 3.49, 3.355, 3.363, 3.234, 3.129, 3.315, 3.341, 
    3.328, 3.315, 3.334, 3.396, 3.346, 3.338, 3.371, 3.35, 3.423, 
    3.539, 3.651, 3.894, 3.983, 3.651, 3.747, 3.873, 3.978, 3.912, 
    3.284, 3.339, 3.395, 3.451, 3.442, 3.507, 3.533, 3.353, 3.378, 
    3.252, 3.423, 3.259, 3.246, 3.451, 3.287, 3.499)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), .Names = c("symbol", 
"date", "dynmes", "total.assets", "treat", "ban", "treat.ban", 
"market.to.book", "leverage"))
```

Comment: A couple of points: 1) If you only have a single "ban", that occurs on a particular date, then ban and date are collinear, and ban can be omitted. 2) Since `log(total.assets)` returns NA, it is likely that you have some invalid entry (probably a 0) in total.assets. If this is the case, using `log(total.assets + 1)` will solve that issue.

Comment: 1) The ban periods lasts 14 days, so that the `ban` variable is `TRUE` on 14 dates. The original sample covers a period of  403 days. 2) `log(total.assets)` is only NA in the example data provided in the post. In my original sample the coefficients is computed in a regular manner.

Comment: I assume that you have fixed effects for each day. If yes, then these fixed effects will soak up all the variability for the ban period, making that variable unnecessary and collinear. The interaction of ban and treatment (the variable of interest) will be fine.

Comment: Yes, I use daily fixed effects. In fact, if I run the model without fixed effects, all coefficients are computed. Adding (daily) time fixed effects causes the coefficient `ban` to be NA, just like adding firm fixed effects causes the coeffiient `treat`to be NA, and in the final model with both effects only the `treat.ban` coefficient can be estimated. But does this necessarily have to be this way? And if yes, why?

Comment: This is a methodological question better posted on crossValidated. By controlling for daily fixed effects, you are controlling for the ban period (as well as every other day). Similarly, by adding firm fixed effects you are controlling for the firm(s) that is(are) banned already. Think about a 2X2 identity matrix. The vector (1, 1) is a linear combination of the vectors (0, 1) and (1, 0). This is what is happening here when you add the unnecessary ban and treat indicators.