# How come I only get NA when running the felm (fixed effects linear model) code in R?

Tags: r, na, fixed

```
dput(TandC[1:5, ])
```

Hi guys!
I want to run this fixed effects linear model in R, but I get this strange error when I run the code, followed by an output full of "NA". This is the error I get:

`Warning in chol.default(mat, pivot = TRUE, tol = tol) : the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite`

And this is my model:

```
m6a <- felm(ihs(RD_expenses) ~ merger_it_post1 + merger_it_post2 + merger_it_post3 + age + ihs(rd_expenses_pre1) + ihs(employees_pre1) + ihs(profit_pre1) + factor(year)
       | company | 0 | company,
       data = TandC,
       na.action,
       subset = RD_expenses > pcts[1] & RD_expenses < pcts[2])
```

summary(m6a)

The `merger_it` variables are dummies and the rest are covariates.
I do have some NAs in the `profit_pre1` for example, but this is because those variables are formed based on tje `period` variable.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, as the model without the covariates (so only the merger dummies and fixed effects) is working perfectly fine.

Can anyone help me out? Much appreciated!!

Comment: This question might give you some clues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45483291/fixed-effects-estimation-with-felm-from-lfe-package-causes-rank-deficiency

Comment: Thank! But it's not really what i'm looking for..

Answer (score 0):

Last time I encountered this error, it was because my dataframe has NAs that made it impossible to compute the model. I see that you wrote `na.action` - maybe you wanted to specify to ignore all NAs? Like this

```r
    m6a <- felm(ihs(RD_expenses) ~ merger_it_post1 + merger_it_post2 + merger_it_post3 + age + ihs(rd_expenses_pre1) + ihs(employees_pre1) + ihs(profit_pre1) + factor(year)
           | company | 0 | company,
           data = TandC,
           na.omit,
           subset = RD_expenses > pcts[1] & RD_expenses < pcts[2])
```